# Working directory when running a Docker container with a Docker-Compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up a CI pipeline which uses a Docker container to run tests. The pipeline is supposed to create a container based on an image I already have and remove that container when it's finished.

For my tests I need to mount a few volumes and bind a few ports from my runner to my container, so to simplify things I want to use a **docker-compose** file that's constantly stored in `/home/runner/docker/docker-compose.yml` on my runner.

The problem is as follows:
 in my `docker-compose.yml` I have the following lines, binding the current working directory to the HTML folder in my container :

```
volumes:
  - .:var/www/html
```

When I use the command `docker-compose -f "/home/runner/docker/docker-compose.yml" -d`, `.` should be whichever folder GitLab CI cloned my project to, not `/home/runner/docker`as is currently the case.

Is there a way to make it so that `.` is my cloned project folder (without hardcoding the name), or am I better off just executing a `docker run` in my GitLab CI script?

Comment: Does symlinking the `docker-compose.yml` file into the current directory and running `docker-compose` from there help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use an environment variable to define the path to the repo, so that instead of

```
volumes:
  - .:var/www/html
```

you have

```
volumes:
  - ${YOUR_REPO}:var/www/html
```

This way you only need to set `YOUR_REPO` before running `docker-compose` and that's it.